# Вытащить количество гитхаб репозиториев с профиля юзера - GitHub API

Tags: javascript, github-api

Цель - получить переменную в джаваскрипте, выводя которую мы будем видеть количество репозиториев пользователя.

Код -

```
const repo_count = function get_count_public_repos() {
    fetch('https://api.github.com/users/serhii73').then(resp => resp.json()).then(jsonResult => {
        console.log(jsonResult['public_repos']);
        return jsonResult['public_repos'];
    })
}

let public_repos = repo_count()
```

Запускаем код - 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Проблема -
`public_repos` - пустая. Почему там нет цифры?
Как изменить код, чтобы количество репозиториев пользователя было в переменной?

Comment: у вас функция `repo_count` ничего не возвращает. И даже если бы что-то возвращала, то точно не то, что вам нужно, поскольку промисы асинхронны и вытащить "наружу" результат из них нельзя

Comment: @smellyshovel и как в таком случае действовать? Если мне нужно число "покласть" в переменную?

Comment: Работать с результатом выполнения промиса нужно в методе .then. Поэтому вы можете возвращать промис из функции, а .then навешивать на сам вызов: repo_count().then(...). Другой вариант - async-await (посмотрите ссылку выше, там в первом ответе Grundy первый же пример очень похож на ваш кейс).

Comment: А именно вынести переменную, доступную внутри `then` за его пределы, увы не получится. Точнее, чисто технически, сделать это можно (замыкания), но ожидаемого результата это вам не принесет. Так что просто вешайте `then` на код верхнего уровня. Либо юзайте async/await, балго транспиляторы его уже понимают.